# aligning images and text horizontally and vertically within div

Tags: css, html, image, vertical-alignment, alignment

This question is flooded galore all over the internet, yet every where I go, I fail trying to implement it.

First the code.
I spent over an hour on this, and could not align the images how I wanted.
Essentially first row have picture left aligned and text next to it, centered vertically.
Next 'row', picture right-aligned, with text next to it centered vertically.

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TK9Pq/1/)

I spent 5 MINUTES on this using table to get it how I wanted it.

[table jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aGZj/)

If you can figure out how to make the two look identical,  then you are a superstar in my book.  If you can solve that, then can someone please tell me why in the heck it is so freakin hard to align or orient text in the world today of CSS??  Why use divs over tables??  I feel like the coding standards have only gotten more complicated over the years.

Sorry for the rant, but since I took the time to post this to possibly help others, and not give up..yet, I had to blow off some steam :)

Comment: There are no pictures in your jsFiddle so is hard to tell what you want. Just upload them to tinypic or something and reference them in the code.

Comment: the pictures don't really matter, just getting them to align is my goal.  Their height is defined as 225px. (width in my page ~250px).  so you can reference any random picture on the internet if you wanted.

Comment: Is your layout going to be fluid or fixed width? If fluid then you can probably achieve this easily with fluid grids, such as 960gs fluid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want flexible structure,you should  use the div. Because the Tables are fixed. For example: The bottom cell should have same width with the top cell. They can't be different from each other. Table cells are linked to together.You cannot separate them. So you should use tables for very simple design. To put it more clearly,You should use div for flexible,complex,veried design. If you need to use the div, you should use div ;)

you can make what you want to do with using the div, this way .

http://jsfiddle.net/5aGZj/1/

Comment: I am not too familiar with the table , table-row and table-cell property.  Is this a way to sort things such as columns/rows, but within a div?  It seems to have the same effect as tables, but perhaps a little more flexibility row to row or column to column!?

Comment: No,you can use them for other elements too.(ul,li,span,a...etc). Similar to the table to the other elements with these properties.
http://brugbart.com/Tutorials/display-table-tutorial